# DataSet Update applying default values for new record rather than values that have been set

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, dataset

I have a fairly simple table called MortgageFees in a DataSet (.Net Framework 4.0).  It is linked to a parent Mortgages table through a MortgageID.  When new records are inserted in the MortgageFees table for an existing Mortgage there is no problem.  However, when creating a new Mortgage, after the Mortgage has been saved and has a new ID number, the .Net DBAdapter for the MortgageFees table writes out the original records default values rather than the values that have been set.  Looking at a dump of the record before saving and after shows there are values in all of the fields that need values.  However, using the SQL Trace tool, what the Insert command is writing out is the original record default values. This code has been working for a number of years but occasionally glitches when saving new Mortgages and MortgageFees.

The insert command is fairly simple:

```
INSERT INTO [MortgageFees] ([MortgageID], [ApplicationID], [ConstructionDrawID], [CompanyID], [TransactionTypeID], [Rate], [Amount], [ToInvestorRate], [ToInvestorAmount], [BrokerName], [BrokerContactID], [Memo], [SortOrder], [UsedForAPRCalculation], [DeductFromPrincipal], [UseForNewMortgages], [UseForRenewedMortgages]) VALUES (@MortgageID, @ApplicationID, @ConstructionDrawID, @CompanyID, @TransactionTypeID, @Rate, @Amount, @ToInvestorRate, @ToInvestorAmount, @BrokerName, @BrokerContactID, @Memo, @SortOrder, @UsedForAPRCalculation, @DeductFromPrincipal, @UseForNewMortgages, @UseForRenewedMortgages);
SELECT MortgageFeeID, MortgageID, ApplicationID, ConstructionDrawID, CompanyID, TransactionTypeID, Rate, Amount, ToInvestorRate, ToInvestorAmount, BrokerName, BrokerContactID, Memo, SortOrder, UsedForAPRCalculation, DeductFromPrincipal, UseForNewMortgages, UseForRenewedMortgages, Version FROM MortgageFees WHERE (MortgageFeeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()) ORDER BY SortOrder, Amount DESC
```

This code was generated by the DataSet editor and has not been modified by me. A dump of the record shows the following (note the TransactionTypeID has a value and then the RowError stating that it does not):

```
{Armada.BusinessComponents.dsEditMortgage.MortgageFeesRow}
    _action: Nothing {0}
    _columns: {System.Data.DataColumnCollection}
    _countColumnChange: 6
    _element: Nothing
    _lastChangedColumn: {MortgageID}
    _objectTypeCount: 1723
    _rbTreeNodeId: 1
    _rowID: 1
    _table: {MortgageFees}
    Amount: 375D
    ApplicationID: DBNull
    BrokerContactID: DBNull
    BrokerName: DBNull
    CompaniesRow: Nothing
    CompanyID: DBNull
    ConstructionDrawID: DBNull
    ConstructionDrawsRow: Nothing
    DeductFromPrincipal: False
    Element: Nothing
    error: {System.Data.DataError}
    HasErrors: True
    HasPropertyChanged: True
.
.
.

    Memo: DBNull
    MortgageApplicationRow: Nothing
    MortgageFeeID: -1
    MortgageID: 857
    MORTGAGESRow: {Armada.BusinessComponents.dsEditMortgage.MORTGAGESRow}
    newRecord: 0
    ObjectID: 1722
    oldRecord: -1
    Rate: 0.75D
    RBTreeNodeId: 1
    RowError: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TransactionTypeID', table 'ArmadaDev.dbo.MortgageFees'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated."
    rowID: 1
    RowState: Added {4}
    SortOrder: 1
    Table: {MortgageFees}
    tableMortgageFees: {MortgageFees}
    tempRecord: 1
    ToInvestorAmount: 375D
    ToInvestorRate: 100D
    TransactionTypeID: 8
    TX_TYPESRow: {Armada.BusinessComponents.dsEditMortgage.TX_TYPESRow}
    UsedForAPRCalculation: False
    UseForNewMortgages: False
    UseForRenewedMortgages: False
```

The dump above was taken just after running the Update method on the adapter.  When the SQL Trace tool is used at the same time it shows the following SQL being issued:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [MortgageFees] ([MortgageID], [ApplicationID], [ConstructionDrawID], [CompanyID], [TransactionTypeID], [Rate], [Amount], [ToInvestorRate], [ToInvestorAmount], [BrokerName], [BrokerContactID], [Memo], [SortOrder], [UsedForAPRCalculation], [DeductFromPrincipal], [UseForNewMortgages], [UseForRenewedMortgages]) VALUES (@MortgageID, @ApplicationID, @ConstructionDrawID, @CompanyID, @TransactionTypeID, @Rate, @Amount, @ToInvestorRate, @ToInvestorAmount, @BrokerName, @BrokerContactID, @Memo, @SortOrder, @UsedForAPRCalculation, @DeductFromPrincipal, @UseForNewMortgages, @UseForRenewedMortgages);
SELECT MortgageFeeID, MortgageID, ApplicationID, ConstructionDrawID, CompanyID, TransactionTypeID, Rate, Amount, ToInvestorRate, ToInvestorAmount, BrokerName, BrokerContactID, Memo, SortOrder, UsedForAPRCalculation, DeductFromPrincipal, UseForNewMortgages, UseForRenewedMortgages, Version FROM MortgageFees WHERE (MortgageFeeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()) ORDER BY SortOrder, Amount DESC',
N'@MortgageID int,@ApplicationID int,@ConstructionDrawID int,@CompanyID int,@TransactionTypeID int,@Rate decimal(6,3),@Amount money,@ToInvestorRate decimal(6,3),@ToInvestorAmount money,@BrokerName nvarchar(4000),@BrokerContactID int,@Memo nvarchar(4000),@SortOrder tinyint,@UsedForAPRCalculation bit,@DeductFromPrincipal bit,@UseForNewMortgages bit,@UseForRenewedMortgages bit',
@MortgageID=-1,@ApplicationID=NULL,@ConstructionDrawID=NULL,@CompanyID=NULL,
@TransactionTypeID=NULL,@Rate=NULL,@Amount=$0.0000,@ToInvestorRate=NULL,@ToInvestorAmount=$0.0000,@BrokerName=NULL,@BrokerContactID=NULL,@Memo=NULL,@SortOrder=1,@UsedForAPRCalculation=0,@DeductFromPrincipal=0,@UseForNewMortgages=0,@UseForRenewedMortgages=0
```

As you can see, the values being issued to the command do not match the ones in the record. The commands in the Adapter were set using the 'Update' method on the Table in the DataSet Designer.  Every other code in the application that uses DataSets continues to work correctly (more or less, although I think this problem may be showing up in other areas but with less visibility to the user).

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that calling EndEdit on the DataGridView and on the underlying BindingSource is not enough.  I added an extension function that walks all of the rows of the DataTable and calls EndEdit.  This forces the unsaved changes to become active.  The code now looks like this:

```
    grdMortgageFees.EndEdit() ' force this, again, just in case
    bsMortgageFees.EndEdit() ' And push it down from the Binding Source
    Me.DsEditMortgage1.MortgageFees.MarkAsEdited() ' Now mark the records as edited
    cnt += Me.DsEditMortgage1.MortgageFees.Save(dbConnection) ' and save the changes.
```

The extensions function is simple and looks like this:

```
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Apply EndEdit to all of the rows in a table.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="Table">DataTable to apply this method to.</param>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        <Extension()>
        Public Sub MarkAsEdited(Table As DataTable)
            For Each row As DataRow In Table.Rows
                row.EndEdit()
            Next
        End Sub
```

I still believe there is a bug in the underlying Microsoft .net framework code, possibly in the BindingSource which does not seem to pass on the EndEdit to the record level.